# Table Total values of some columns not showing, power bi

Tags: powerbi, tableview, dax, calculation, subtotal

I have this table. All of the columns are after measure. As you can see some column totals are shown, some are not.

If some total values are correct, others are not (for example,only 3 and 5 column totals are right)

And I want summarize 1,4,5,7 columns and average values for 2, 6 columns

Any help appreciated (My apologies, I couldn't create tables nor post images because of pundits)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C50Xf.png)

And this is how measure looks for 2nd column (%Выдачи)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XiN3.png)

Comment: The total result of each column depends on your measure calculation. To help you we need all your wrong measures' text.

Comment: How can I contact you to give information in detail about given issue?

Comment: Please try to improve and clarify your question, Add samples, details etc. It would be nice if you add them as text instead of images also.

Comment: I edited my post. Please, take a look at it

Comment: For your %Выдачи measure the problem is that *Total* isn't equal to 'Дамира Сыдыбаева' and also it isn't BLANK. So you get 0, as expected. To debug your measure I would advice you to test it placing variables (a,b,c) into RETURN statement (for example, RETURN a). This way you will see what your variables return.